# Include the value from the custom field in the wp_tag_cloud arguments

Tags: php, wordpress, tags

Using a shortcode `[tagsListfoot]`, I display a cloud of placemarks in the basement of the site. Now it looks like this:

```
add_shortcode( 'tagsListfoot', 'getTagListfoot' );
    function getTagListfoot() {
    global $post;

    $args = array( 
        'taxonomy'  => 'tags_type',
        'order'     => 'RAND',
        'number'    => '10',
    );
    wp_tag_cloud( $args );
}
```

Each tag has a custom field (2 radio - "yes" and "no"). Is it possible to add a value from a custom field to the cloud arguments? Ideally, you should only output tags with the value "yes".

I try something like this, but it doesn't help(

```
    add_shortcode( 'tagsListfoot', 'getTagListfoot' );
    function getTagListfoot() {
    global $post;
    $tag_footer = ( 'yes' == get_term_meta( $tag->term_id, 'pokazat-v-podvale' ) );

    $args = array( 
        'taxonomy'  => 'tags_type',
        'order'     => 'RAND',
        'number'    => '10',
        'include'   => $tag_footer,
    );
    wp_tag_cloud( $args );
}
```

Comment: Add a custom field query to your arguments. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#custom-field-post-meta-parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the tip @CBroe

Indeed, can also use `meta_query` to request the value of a custom field. Here's what happened:

```
add_shortcode( 'tagsListfoot', 'getTagListfoot' );
    function getTagListfoot() {
    global $post;
    
    $args = array( 
        'taxonomy'  => 'tags_type',
        'order'     => 'RAND',
        'number'    => '10',
        'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'show_in_foot',
            'value'   => 'yes',
            'compare' => 'IN',
        ),
    ),
    );
    wp_tag_cloud( $args );
}
```